# delete_selected is not called when deleting items from TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

my code:

`class FileAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.File
    extra = 0

    def delete_model(self, request, instance):
        # do extra work
        return super(FileAdmin, self).delete_model(request, instance)

class BannerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (FileAdmin,)

admin.site.register(models.Banner, BannerAdmin)`

when I mark my `File` items for deletion and save the `Banner`, the `delete_model` method on my `FileAdmin` does not get called.

how can I fix that? do I need to write a custom action and replace `django.contrib.admin.actions.delete_selected` with mine? if so, how can I reuse the standard action?

EDIT:

here is my new code for `FileAdmin`:

`class FileAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.File
    extra = 0
    actions = ('my_delete_selected',)

    def my_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        # do extra work
        return actions.delete_selected(self, request, queryset)`

but this did not help. `my_delete_selected` does not get called either... I am using grappelli templates for admin, but I do not think it matters.

Comment: note that your delete signals are not called for bulk deletions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [save_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related)? From the docs:

> The save_related method is given the HttpRequest, the parent ModelForm instance, the list of inline formsets and a boolean value based on whether the parent is being added or changed. Here you can do any pre- or post-save operations for objects related to the parent. Note that at this point the parent object and its form have already been saved.